# How to remove space between citations in reference list for articles using apacite package?

Tags: natbib, apa-style, apacite, journal-publishing, springer

There is an extra space after @article reference unlike &inproceedings. I want to eliminate the extra spacing. And there is also an extra spacing when I use DOI link. How can I remove these extra spacings?

[image: This is the image of the reference list. There is an extra spacing before DOI link and after @article reference =]

```
% These are the packages I have imported

\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-apa]{sn-jnl}
\jyear{2023}%
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous   numbers

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{doi}

%The is code for listing the references 
@article{A2023a,
title={CBAa: Institution},
author={A, G},
Doi = {https://doi.org/10.3390/app12f06}, 
volume={09},
number={2},
pages={90},
year={2023},
}
@inproceedings{A2022,
title={ABC: Institution},
author={A, Ho},
booktitle={Conference on computer vision},
pages={5050--5060},
year={2022}
}
@article{A2023,
title={CBA: Institution},
author={A, K},
year={2023}
}

%This is the code I have used in the main.tex for 
%displaying the doi link. However, there is an extra 
%line of space before the link. 

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\doi}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doi@}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\doi}{\hyper@normalise\doi@}
\renewcommand\doiprefix{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

%I have also tried to reduce the spacing in        
%sn- jnl.cls file by setting 0em in setlength. This 
%helped in reducing the space in inproceeding 
%journals but not for articles. There are       
%still extra spaces after the article references.

\if@APA@refstyle%
  \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}%
  \gdef\NumBib{NO}%
  \bibliographystyle{sn-apacite}%s
  \def\refdoi#1{\urlstyle{rm}\url{#1}}%
  \renewcommand{\doiprefix}{}%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand{\BPBI}{.}% Period between initials - command from         apacite.sty
  }%
  \setlength{\bibsep}{0em}%
  \def\bibfont{\reset@font\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\normalsize\selectfont}%
\fi%
```

I'm trying to achieve a reference list like the one below.

[image]

(Note: I'm using overleaf Latex)

I'm struggling to remove spaces basically. Could anybody kindly help me solve this problem? I'm trying to submit my paper to one of the springer journals.

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example in one code block so we don't have to puzzle together all the code fragments?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have placed all the codes together and placed the description of them right above each code section.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz could you kindly have a look at this? Is there a way I can solve this?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. However it is hard to reproduce your problem. There is no documentclass, no document environment, no citations etc. in your code. One would need to first spend a lot of time to generate a reproducible example before even starting to work on your actual problem.

Comment: Your write-up is confusing: In the title of your query, you appear to state that you employ the `natbib` citation management package; however, your code suggests that you employ the `apacite` citation management package (with option `natbibapa`). Which of these two packages is actually loaded? If it's the `apacite` package, why aren't you employing the `apacite` bibliography style? Either way, why are you redefining critically important macros such as `\doi`? Please clarify.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz my apologies, I'm not so proficient in latex, I have been trying to find ways to reduce the spacings and attempted to use different packages for doing this. I have edited the code and added the document class details and the packages.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your feedback, it is actually apacite package.  I have been trying different codes to display the doi link and this worked but the spacing problem still persists.

Comment: @Mico I initially stated natbib in my question, I have edited the question. Thank you so much.

Comment: Another slightly off-topic remark: Why does your code have `Doi = {https://doi.org/10.3390/app12f06},`. I think it would be better to load the `xurl` package and to write `url = {https://doi.org/10.3390/app12f06},`.